# Trigger to Insert New Row in Records Table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two tables.

The first table is Routes with schema (Train_Number, Route_Status, Time_Status, Route_TM, Departure, Destination) and a second table Records with schema (Train_Number, Time_Status, Route_TM, Departure, Destination).

I need a trigger such that when Route Status changes from 'En-Route' to 'Arrived', It logs the (Train_Number, Time_Status, Date, Departure, Destination) from Routes to Records.

Also in play is another table Configuration with schema (Name, Value). In particular, in that table, I have ('Enable_Logging', 'T')

Here is my attempt at this trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Train_Logging
AFTER UPDATE OF Route_Status ON Routes

FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.route_status = 'Arrived' AND old.route_status = 'En-Route')

DECLARE
logging_flag Configuration.value%type;

BEGIN

SELECT Configuration.value INTO logging_flag FROM Configuration WHERE Configuration = 'Enable_Logging';

IF (logging_flag = 'T') THEN INSERT INTO Records (Train_Number, Time_Status, Date, Departure, Destination) VALUES (SELECT Train_Number, Time_Status, Date, Departure, Destination FROM Routes);
END IF;
END Train_Logging;
```

My errors are
"PL/SQL Statement Ignored" (at logging_flag Configuration.value%type;)
and  "ORA-00936 missing expression" (at BEGIN)

What is wrong with my declaration statement?

Comment: The table definitions you described have a column called `date` which is a reserved word, so it isn't called that unless you created it quoted; and you don't have a column called just `status` as your trigger is expecting. Showing your actual table DDL would make it easier to see what's really wrong.

Comment: sorry, I renamed everything so I didn't have to post a lot of unnecessary out-of-context things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring problems with your schema as stated - you seem to have a field called `date` which is not allowed, unless it's quoted, and you're checking a `status` field that doesn't existing the table description you showed, and you're referring to `configuration.configuration` in a `select` instead of `configuration.name` - with a bit of tweaking you get an error stack like:

```
8/122          PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression
8/30           PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

And line 8 appears to be the `logging_flag` declaration; but actually the line numbers in the error refer to the PL/SQL block, not to the trigger definition that comes before that, so line 8 is really line 14 in your statement. If you split that line out so the `insert` goes onto a new line, and the `values` also goes onto a new line, the stack becomes:

```
10/9           PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression
9/1            PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

So the `insert` is being ignored because there's something wrong with the `values` clause. If you did want to insert from a select you wouldn't use the `values` keyword at all; you'd do:

```
INSERT INTO Records (Train_Number, Time_Status, Train_Date,
  Departure, Destination)
SELECT Train_Number, Time_Status, Train_Date, Departure, Destination
FROM Routes;
```

(You can use a `select` inside a `values` clause, but only to get a single value, and then it would in another set of parentheses, and that isn't what you want here.)

But you don't want or need select from the table you're inserting into. Your `select` has no `where` clause so you'd be copying the entire `routes` table into the `records` table for every time any row was updated, which surely isn;t what you want. You only want to copy the particular row affected by the update. But you don't need a `select` for that, you have all the values in the `new` and `old` pseudo-rows:

```
INSERT INTO Records (Train_Number, Time_Status, Train_Date,
  Departure, Destination)
VALUES (:NEW.Train_Number, :NEW.Time_Status, :NEW.Train_Date,
  :NEW.Departure, :NEW.Destination);
```

So assuming your `date` column is really called `train_date`, and you want to check `route_status` has changed, it will look like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Train_Logging
AFTER UPDATE OF Route_Status ON Routes
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.route_status = 'Arrived' AND old.route_status = 'En-Route')
DECLARE
  logging_flag Configuration.value%type;
BEGIN
  SELECT Configuration.value
  INTO logging_flag
  FROM Configuration
  WHERE Name = 'Enable_Logging';

  IF (logging_flag = 'T') THEN
    INSERT INTO Records (Train_Number, Time_Status, Train_Date,
      Departure, Destination)
    VALUES (:NEW.Train_Number, :NEW.Time_Status, :NEW.Train_Date,
      :NEW.Departure, :NEW.Destination);
  END IF;
END Train_Logging;
/
```

With some made-up data, and guessing some of your data types:

```
insert into configuration values ('Enable_Logging', 'T');
insert into routes values (1, 'En-Route', 'On-time', trunc(sysdate),
  trunc(sysdate) + 10/24, 'New York');
update routes set route_status = 'Arrived' where train_number = 1;
select * from records;

TRAIN_NUMBER TIME_STATUS TRAIN_DATE DEPARTURE DESTINATION
------------ ----------- ---------- --------- -----------
           1 On-time     29-APR-14  29-APR-14 New York
```

Incidentally, keeping the status values as strings makes them harder to manage as you have to always enter everything with exactly the right case. It would be better, generally, to have a look-up table of status codes with a numeric primary key, and have these tables with a foreign-key to that master status table. Then you insert the key value instead of the text, so you don't have to worry about the case etc., and if the wording ever changes you only have to update it in one place. Of course, you have to join to that table to retrieve the text values, but that's not a great hardship.

Comment: This actually taught me 2 things: error codes do not give actual lines, and a more clear (and working) syntax for inserting values. I did alter some of the field names in my op in order to give a more clear context. The real thing is a lot more messy.

Comment: @KyleGrage - the error codes do give actual lines, but relative to the PL/SQL code, which is particularly confusing with triggers as they are a mix of SQL and PL/SQL. Glad it helped though *8-)